# How to publish/use SNAPSHOT Maven Archetypes

Tags: maven-3, maven-archetype

I'm trying to generate a SNAPSHOT maven archetype, publish it to Sonatype's OSS repo: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/funcatron/starter/

The publishing happens correctly. However, when I try to `mvn archetype:generate` from the SNAPSHOT, things do not work:

`mvn archetype:generate  -B \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=funcatron \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=starter \
    -DarchetypeVersion=0.3.0-SNAPSHOT \
    -DgroupId=my.stellar \
    -DartifactId=thang \
    -DarchetypeRepository=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/`

The archetype is not found:

`[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository.
[WARNING] Add a repsoitory with id 'archetype' in your settings.xml if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
[WARNING] The POM for funcatron:starter:jar:0.3.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------`

So... what am I doing wrong? Is there something I should be adding to the [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/funcatron/funcatron/blob/master/starter/pom.xml) to publish the SNAPSHOT artifact so it can be found via `mvn archetype:generate`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.xml add archetype repository:

```
   <repository>
      <id>archetype</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
```